# How do I modify Operational Attributes in OpenLDAP from Java/JNDI?

Tags: java, ldap, jndi, openldap

We are working on a custom password reset tool which is currently able to reset the passwords for users (using the admin DN), but I need to also remove/modify some Operational Attributes in order to completely handle the business use cases. I connect to the LDAP server using:

```
private void connect() throws NamingException {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, LDAP_CTX_FACTORY);
    props.put(PROVIDER_URL, format("ldap://%s:%d/", config.ldapHost(), config.ldapPort()));
    props.put(SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, config.ldapBindPassword());
    props.put(SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, config.ldapBindUser());
    props.put(SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    props.put(REFERRAL, "follow");
    props.put(BATCHSIZE, "1000");
    connection = new InitialLdapContext(props, null);
    connection.setRequestControls(LDAPControls.controls());

    LOG.debug("Successfully completed bind to LDAP server '{}'", config.ldapHost());
    connected = true;
}
```

And I need to modify some operational attributes to do things like unlock accounts/update modified time/etc...

```
    List<BasicAttribute> attrs = new ArrayList<>();
    List<ModificationItem> mods = new ArrayList<>();
    // Set password hash
    attrs.add(new BasicAttribute("userPassword", "{SSHA}" + hashPassword(salt, password)));
    mods.add(new ModificationItem(REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, attrs.get(0)));
    // Set last modified timestamp
    attrs.add(new BasicAttribute("modifyTimestamp", date.withZone(UTC).format(now())));
    mods.add(new ModificationItem(REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, attrs.get(1)));
    // Set password changed time
    attrs.add(new BasicAttribute("pwdChangeTime", date.withZone(UTC).format(now())));
    mods.add(new ModificationItem(REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, attrs.get(2)));
    // Remove password lock
    attrs.add(new BasicAttribute("pwdAccountLockedTime"));
    mods.add(new ModificationItem(REMOVE_ATTRIBUTE, attrs.get(3)));
    // Clear password failure time
    attrs.add(new BasicAttribute("pwdFailureTime"));
    mods.add(new ModificationItem(REMOVE_ATTRIBUTE, attrs.get(4)));
    this.reconnect();
    ModificationItem[] modItems = new ModificationItem[mods.size()];
    mods.toArray(modItems);
    connection.modifyAttributes(getDN(email), modItems);
    LOG.debug("Completed update of user password for '{}'", email);
    return true;
```

But when I run this, I get:

```
LDAP: error code 21 - modifyTimestamp: value #0 invalid per syntax
```

Could anyone help me to figure out why?

Comment: The `modifyTimtestamp` attribute is not modifiable by the user. Strangely though, updating the password or whatnot does not seem to update this attribute. Perhaps only modification of other attributes will achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I modify Operational Attributes in OpenLDAP from Java/JNDI?

You don't. The server does. That's what 'operational attribute' means.

> I need to also remove/modify some Operational Attributes in order to completely handle the business use cases

Bad luck.

You should be using the 'ppolicy' overlay and the associated extended password-modify operations, rather than rolling all this yourself. It  does everything you need, and if it doesn't you need to adjust your needs ;-)

NB You should not hash the password yourself. OpenLDAP will do that for you when configured correctly.

Comment: ppolicy IS in place and works great when regular users update their passwords. The problem is that this is a password reset tool which means it authenticates as the admin DN, and ppolicy will not prevent the admin DN from doing anything.

Comment: No, the problem is that (a) you aren't using the extended password-modify operation in the code above, which means you are completely bypassing the ppolicy overlay with this code, and (b) you should not use the internal manager DN for anything: you should define an administrative user with the appropriate permissions and use that. The manager DN is for OoenLDAP itself. It should never be used by any person or application.

Comment: Could you explain further or provide a link?

Comment: See [*man slapo-ppolicy*](http://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=slapo-ppolicy&sektion=5&apropos=0&manpath=OpenLDAP+2.3-Release), specifically the first paragraph: 'intercepts, decodes and applies specific password policy controls'.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the links and the clarification!

Comment: My comment above that you need to use the extended password modify request with `ppolicy` is not correct: you don't, but it is much more convenient, and it provides an autogeneration feature that otherwise doesn't exist. If you don't use the extended operation, you have to use both a delete and an insert to change the `userPassword` attribute if `pwdSafeModify` is TRUE in the policy, supplying the old vale for deletion and the new value for insertion. You must still however not use the rootDN account for password modify operations.